# jQuery tabs: fadeIn/fadeOut the content on tab switch

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

How to trigger fadeIn fadeOut effect in Jquery tabs on switching from one to another

Comment: Can you post here the code you already have? We will probably need something to start with.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) . It gets triggered when a new tab is activated :)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.newPanel.hide().fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
  });
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRZKz/) to help you